# Cannot initiate an abstract class because members are abstract

Tags: c++, clone, abstract

I am new to polymorphism, this is a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532366/cannot-instantiate-abstract-class-because-members-are-abstract) but the solution didn't help me. 
The exact error is:

> Circle.cpp(34) : error C2259: 'Circle' : cannot instantiate abstract class
>           due to following members:
>          'void Shape::particle(const Ray &,const int&)' : is abstract

I have tried to read up on this and what I think is  that the clone() member function,calls Circle's copy constructor to copy the state of this into the newly created Circle object and tries to initialize the 'particle' (which it cant do).
If I am right: how do I correct this?
If I am wrong...what is it doing (what am I doing wrong) and how do i correct it.

```
class Shape {
public:

virtual void particle(const Ray& ray, const int& count) = 0;      
...
virtual Shape* clone()  const = 0;   
private:
vector<Ray>  incoming_ray; 
vector<int>  counts;
};

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
Circle* clone()  const;   //covariant return type
virtual void
particle(const Ray& ray, const int& count);
 ...
};
```

And then

```
Circle* Circle::clone()  const { return new Circle(*this); }

void
Circle::particle(const Ray& rays, const int& count){
incoming_ray.push_back(inc_ray);
counts.push_back(counts);};
```

I tried

```
virtual void particle(const Ray& ray, const int& count) const = 0; 
                                                          ^
```

but still got the same error?

Thanks

Comment: I just tried to compile your code and I don't get the error... is it really the exact same code that is causing your problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
virtual void particle(const Ray& ray, const int& count) const = 0;
                                                        ^^^^^^
```

Makes it a altogether different method. And is not same as:

```
virtual void particle(const Ray& ray, const int& count) = 0;
```

Eventually, what you have is a new method in your derived class which is pure virtual, It does not override the Base class pure virtual method. Since there is no overidding it leaves your derived class with an inherited pure virtual function which it doesn't implement and it makes your derived class as Abstract class as well.

To override a Base class virtual method You need to have exact same definition of the method in Base class to override it(*Co-variant types* are allowed though).

Comment: Thanks Als - could you maybe explain why? I did that because I read it on another forum. They didn't explain fully though.

Comment: This is clear. But he says he "also" tried this, and it "also" failed. So, _before_ that, he tried to compile without this extra const. Why did _that_ fail?

Comment: AFAIK his code compiles and works fine (just tried it). Effectively when he added the const at the end of the base class method, that caused the error... could that be the actual problem ?

Comment: @user1002744: I hope the answer explains well enough. As long as you remove the `const` and have exactly the same function signature that in Base class, it should work.

Comment: @DanielDaranas: I don't know why it failed, it should not have failed, I explained in detail the reason for failure and that should clear it up for OP(*I hope*).

Comment: I removed the const and copy amd pasted the same functions signature(maybe a typo). I now get the same error but for a second inherited class 'Sphere'. However, in Sphere I don't have the function 'particle'. Do each inherited class need the 'particle' function

Comment: @user1002744: Here's the rule: *Every class inheriting from an Abstract class **must implement all pure virtual functions** of the abstract Base class or the derived class becomes an abstract class too!*. So Yes `Sphere` needs to implement `particle()` too.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be working. I have a linking error now though. But I'll try figure that out. Thanks for the help.